# Configuring a local network for WCF Security modes

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have several machines connected through a wireless router.

**When I build a WCF Service in one of the machines with "Security mode = 'None'", then I don't have any problem building client applications that access and use that service from other machines.**

But when I try to use a security mode, say "Security mode='Message'", then I start having problems, I get a **SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service**.

Each machine has it's machine name, windows user name and password. I allow peer to peer file access between them.

I'm using netTcpBinding this time.

Please, I need help here...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set 'clientCredentialType' to 'Windows'? The configuration below assumes your sevice pc and client pc are in the same Windows domain.

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
   <binding name = "mybinding">
     <security mode="Message">
       <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
     </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in networking. How do I set the configuration you are telling me?. I have several windows 7 computers connected to a wireless router, and my internet connection is based on dynamic IP address. How do I set the same domain for all my machines? 
Do I have to install Remote Server Administration Tools or other tools?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. For networking, as long as you can log in your pc with Windows Domain login instead of workgroup login, you can use the <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>. For general idea about security mode = "Message", here are some links  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884(v=vs.110).aspx  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/308dcb5a-34c0-415b-a7d3-3ec9d142849a/how-messages-are-encrypted-when-security-mode-is-message?forum=wcf    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729709(v=vs.110).aspx